# How to make MySQl update faster for large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-update

I would like to optimise an update query of this table as it currently takes a couple of seconds to execute. I am using MySQL 5.6

```
UPDATE skus1 SET `available` = '1', `locked` = NULL WHERE `locked` IS NOT NULL AND `locked` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

I would like to optimise this query also

```
UPDATE skus1 SET `available` = '2', `locked` = NOW() WHERE sku = '111111'
```

I have a SELECT query that runs fast now I've added my indexes

Here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `skus1` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sku` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `locked` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `sku_2` (`sku`,`locked`),
 KEY `available` (`available`),
 KEY `locked` (`locked`),
 KEY `sku` (`sku`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=500001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: How many records are being updated?

Comment: @Barmar it could be anything from 1 to probably about 50, it could be anything but I have 1 million rows

Comment: If you're only updating a few rows, it shouldn't be much slower than the `SELECT` query with the same `WHERE` clause. They both use the same indexes.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the second update query after i removed the `sku` index. I have a transaction and the first update and a select both execute in milliseconds but the second update is a lot slower (over 2 seconds) to to update one record

Comment: If you remove the index, it will have to search the entire table to find matching rows. You need an index to make the `WHERE` clause fast.

Comment: Could it be the UNIQUE key causing the problem?

Comment: No, I don't think so. And since `sku` is a prefix on the `sku_2` index, you shouldn't need a separate index just on `sku`.